# How to change default path in Razor Views in Xamarin?

Tags: razor, xamarin, xamarin.android, relative-path, xamarin-studio

The problem I am facing is this:

```
<div data-role="footer">
    <a class="ui-btn" href="RV2.cshtml">Anchor</a>
    <p>THINGS WRITTEN IN FOOTER</p>
</div>
```

In href, I am passing the name of file as it is, because RV2.cshtml is in Views folder and this file, from which I am calling RV2, is also in Views folder. But its not working this way. I have to put RV2.cshtml in Assets folder and then this HTML link starts working.

Why is that?? And I want all my views in Views folder not in Assets folder. What should I do to achieve that??

Here is the snapshot of folders:

[image]

Now this works fine.

But I want it the following way:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just not possible for the `WebView` to access stuff outside assets. The files outside get compiled, while assets are not being touched and just packaged with the APK file.

Comment: so what are you saying, i should put my views in the assets now ??

Comment: Just like in your first screenshot. It is a limitation of the Android platform, which does not support embedded resources outside of assets. That is just the reality, conform to it, or fail :)